# How to login in an external HTML page (.aspx) loaded with mx.controls.HTML

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, air

I have to load external page (.aspx) with login form. I do it using html.location My code:

```
protected function btn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
  html_container.setVisible(false); 
  frm.url = "https://externalserver/user_mngmnt/login.aspx"; 
  var params:Object = {}; 
  params["ctl00$PageContent$txtUserId"] = "USER";
  params["ctl00$PageContent$txtPassword"] = "PASS"; 
  frm.resultFormat = "text" frm.send(params);
  frm.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,frm_onResult);
  frm.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,onFault); 
} 
protected function frm_onResult(evt:ResultEvent):void 
{ 
  html_container.location = "https://externalserver/logged.aspx";
  html_container.setVisible(true); 
}
```

When I try to log in I'm back to login page.

Is there any way to pass parameters (login/password) and to hold all other from aspx page (including SESSION, __EVENTVALIDATION, ...)?

If not, maybe there is a possibility to pass values from AIR app into aspx form fields and then invoke a button click inside a page loaded within html_container?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `frm`? Is it a `RemoteObject` ?